# Axial correction to electron wave function in the broken phase

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, renormalization

Suppose that, in the standard model, the lightest particles were the electron, electron neutrino and $W$ boson.

I want to calculate, at 1-loop,  the $\beta$-function of $g_{2L}$ in the regime where only these three particles are 'active'. For that, I need the wavefunction renormalization of the electron and neutrino, expressed through counterterms $\delta Z_e, \delta Z_\nu$. Focusing on the electron one, we have the only diagram

[image]

This, of course, would give a residue in the $\epsilon$ expansion which is proportional to the left-handed projector (or, at least, has axial corrections). Normally, we expect that the infinity may be absorbed in a counterterm of the form $i\delta Z_e{p}\cdot \gamma$. In my situation, what is the correct procedure/interpretation? Just add an axial counterterm even though the original Lagrangian does not have such a term?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a chiral counterterm with $\delta Z_{e_{L}}\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})p_{\mu}$ instead of a the vector counterterm in the question.  The theory already *does* already have a term with the structure of this counterterm, because the kinetic term for the leptons can be split into left- and right-handed pieces.  The right-handed electron and neutrino fields are sterile in this theory and do not need to be renormalized at all.